# How to Plot real-Time Sensor Value that Received from Bluetooth Modul in MPAndroidChart on kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth, mpandroidchart

I have a sensor and by connecting it to an Arduino board I can see the sensor signals in the Serial Plotter in the form of a chart on Arduino IDE.
I want to see the same signals on my APP in real time by using a Bluetooth module.
I'm using the **MPAndroidChart** library to plot a chart in Kotlin.
To plot a chart using MPAndroidChart and for more information on how to use MPAndroidChart,
I checked the sample program code that published in Google Play from the following link in Github
https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart
and converted the Java code to Kotlin, and now I can  Plot chart with random numbers.
But I plan to plot my own graph using sensor data that received via Bluetooth.
I wrote a **ReceiveData** function and I want to get the data with this method and give it to the **addEntry** function so that instead of plotting a graph with random numbers, I plot my graph with Bluetooth data.
But I have no idea what to do.
By calling the **feedMultiple** function in

```
btn_startTest.setOnClickListener { feedMultiple() }
```

and using the following code in **addEntry**  a graph plotting with random numbers.

```
data.addEntry(Entry(set.entryCount.toFloat(), (Math.random() * 40).toFloat() + 30f), 0)
```

But The problem I have is that , I d’not know how to *transfer* the data that received via Bluetooth to the **addEntry** function and use them instead of random numbers.
*This is the complete code of my application:*

```
class ElectromyographyAnalysis : AppCompatActivity(), OnChartValueSelectedListener {

    companion object {
        val TAG = "EMGSensor"
        val APP_NAME = "EMGSensor"

        var m_myUUID: UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb")
        var m_bluetoothSocket: BluetoothSocket? = null
        lateinit var m_progress: ProgressDialog
        lateinit var m_bluetoothAdapter: BluetoothAdapter
        var m_isConnected: Boolean = false
        lateinit var m_address: String

        var xVal: Int = 0
        var yVal: Int = 0
    }

    lateinit var emgChart: LineChart


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.electromyography_analysis_layout)

        title = "Electromyography Analysis"

        m_address = intent.getStringExtra(SelectDeviceActivity.EXTRA_ADDRESS).toString()

        ConnectToDevice(this).execute()

        //add this new
        window.setFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
        )


        emgChart = findViewById(R.id.emg_lineChart)
        emgChart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(this)

        // enable description text
        emgChart.description.isEnabled = true

        // enable touch gestures
        emgChart.setTouchEnabled(true)

        // enable scaling and dragging

        // enable scaling and dragging
        emgChart.isDragEnabled = true
        emgChart.setScaleEnabled(true)
        emgChart.setDrawGridBackground(false)

        // if disabled, scaling can be done on x- and y-axis separately
        emgChart.setPinchZoom(true)

        // set an alternative background color
        emgChart.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY)

        val data = LineData()
        data.setValueTextColor(Color.WHITE)

        //add empty data

        // add empty data
        emgChart.data = data

        // get the legend (only possible after setting data)

        // get the legend (only possible after setting data)
        val l: Legend = emgChart.legend

        // modify the legend ...

        // modify the legend ...
        l.form = LegendForm.LINE
        //l.typeface =
        l.textColor = Color.WHITE

        val xl: XAxis = emgChart.xAxis
        //xl.typeface = tfLight
        xl.textColor = Color.WHITE
        xl.setDrawGridLines(false)
        xl.setAvoidFirstLastClipping(true)
        xl.isEnabled = true

        val leftAxis: YAxis = emgChart.getAxisLeft()
        //leftAxis.typeface = tfLight
        leftAxis.textColor = Color.WHITE
        leftAxis.axisMaximum = 100f
        leftAxis.axisMinimum = 0f
        leftAxis.setDrawGridLines(true)

        val rightAxis: YAxis = emgChart.getAxisRight()
        rightAxis.isEnabled = false

        btn_startTest.setOnClickListener { feedMultiple() }
        
    }

    private fun addEntry() {
        val data: LineData = emgChart.data
        if (data != null) {
            var set = data.getDataSetByIndex(0)
            // set.addEntry(...); // can be called as well
            if (set == null) {
                set = createSet()
                data.addDataSet(set)
            }
            data.addEntry(Entry(set.entryCount.toFloat(), (Math.random() * 40).toFloat() + 30f), 0)
            data.notifyDataChanged()

            // let the chart know it's data has changed
            emgChart.notifyDataSetChanged()

            // limit the number of visible entries
            emgChart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(120f)
            // chart.setVisibleYRange(30, AxisDependency.LEFT);

            // move to the latest entry
            emgChart.moveViewToX(data.entryCount.toFloat())

            // this automatically refreshes the chart (calls invalidate())
            // chart.moveViewTo(data.getXValCount()-7, 55f,
            // AxisDependency.LEFT);
        }
    }

    private fun createSet(): LineDataSet {
        val set = LineDataSet(null, "Dynamic Data")
        set.axisDependency = AxisDependency.LEFT
        set.color = ColorTemplate.getHoloBlue()
        set.setCircleColor(Color.WHITE)
        set.lineWidth = 2f
        set.circleRadius = 4f
        set.fillAlpha = 65
        set.fillColor = ColorTemplate.getHoloBlue()
        set.highLightColor = Color.rgb(244, 117, 117)
        set.valueTextColor = Color.WHITE
        set.valueTextSize = 9f
        set.setDrawValues(false)
        return set
    }

    private var thread: Thread? = null

    private fun feedMultiple() {
        if (thread != null)
            thread!!.interrupt()

        val runnable = Runnable { addEntry() }
        thread = Thread {
            for (i in 0..999) {

                // Don't generate garbage runnable inside the loop.
                runOnUiThread(runnable)
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(25)
                } catch (e: InterruptedException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            }
        }
        thread!!.start()
    }

    private fun receiveData() {

        val buffer = ByteArray(1024)
        var bytes: Int
        val handler = Handler()
        var stopWorker = false
        Log.d(TAG, "Inside ReceiveData")

        val workerThread = Thread {
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted && !stopWorker) {

                try {
                    bytes = m_bluetoothSocket!!.inputStream.read(buffer)
                    if (bytes > 0) {
                        val incomingMessage = String(buffer, 0, bytes)
                        Log.d(TAG, "InputStream : $incomingMessage")
                        yVal = incomingMessage.toInt()
                       
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(this , "bytes is less than zero" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                    }
                } catch (ex: IOException) {
                    stopWorker = true
                }
            }
        }
        workerThread.start()
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest I would use EventBus, so you have a  variable listening for data coming from your Bluetooth device.

The eventbus works as a listener.  When you receive your data from the Bluetooth device Android save the event and you can use it wherever in your app, passing it between activities too.

But to do that you nees to register and subscribe. Let's start from the first.

1. Add to your dependencies GreenRobot eventbus in your gradle:

   ```
      implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.2.0'
   ```
2. Create the EventBus (I would make a new object file to make eventbus ordered):

   ```
   data class DataEvent(var dataToSend: Float){}
   ```

Of course, you need to register and subscribe to this events. And how to?

3. Register your eventbus inside your bluetooth receiver you need to register the data to subscribe (where you get the data package from the bluetooth to be clear):

   ```
   val eventData: DataEvent = DataEvent(yourData)
   EventBus.getDefault().post(eventData)
   ```
4. Subscribe, you need to subscribe of course now or you won't see any data being saved into your event class.
   Because you need to plot data, in your ElectromyographyAnalysis Class you need to subscribe to the event:

   ```
   @Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
   public fun onDataReceived(event: DataEvent) {
       if (event.dataToSend != null) {
           dataToPlot = event.dataToSend
       }
       addEntry(dataToPlot) // THIS WILL CALL YOUR ADDENTRY()
   }
   ```

This way you will send to the AddEntry() method every single bit the bluetooth receives and plot them.

5. But, to do so you need to change a bit your AddEntry():

   ```
       private fun addEntry(yourData:DataType) {
             val data: LineData = emgChart.data

        if (data != null) {
             var set = data.getDataSetByIndex(0)
            if (set1 == null) {
                data.addDataSet(set)
            }

            data.addEntry(
                Entry(
                    set.entryCount.toFloat(),
                    datatoplot
                ), 0
            )
            data.notifyDataChanged()

            // let the chart know it's data has changed
            emgChart.notifyDataSetChanged()

            // limit the number of visible entries
            emgChart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(120f)
            // chart.setVisibleYRange(30, AxisDependency.LEFT);

            // move to the latest entry
            emgChart.moveViewToX(data.entryCount.toFloat())

            // this automatically refreshes the chart (calls invalidate())
            // chart.moveViewTo(data.getXValCount()-7, 55f,
            // AxisDependency.LEFT);
        }
    }
   ```
6. You won't need feedMultiple Thread and you will have also a better performant real time graph.

Comment: Just did this sample app that plot data from a text input, but can be followed to load data from any kind of sensors using evenbus -> https://github.com/gello94/Android_-_App_Samples/tree/main/Charting_sample_app